# Python Pandas Write Two Different Files Based on Date Condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using: Python3.6, Pandas 0.22

Looking for any tips or documentation that would steer me in the right direction..

I have a DataFrame which calculates averages for snowfall based on month and location. The file has two years, 2016 and 2017. I am trying to understand if the code I have written is capable of writing to two different files, one for 2016 and one for 2017.

```
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

df['DATE'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DATE'], format='%M/%D/%Y')

df['Year'] = df['DATE'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['DATE'].dt.month
df['Day'] = df['DATE'].dt.day

(df
 .assign(MONTH=df['DATE'].dt.strftime('(%m) %B (%y)'))
 .groupby(['NAME', 'MONTH', 'Year'], as_index=False)['SNOW']
 .agg({'AVERAGE': 'mean'})
)
```

I have attempted many different methods, placing the DF both inside, and outside of these loops:

```
if 'Year' == '2016':
    df = pd.to_csv('average2016.csv', index=False)
else:
    df = pd.to_csv('average2017.csv', index=False)
```

and:

```
if df.loc[df['Year'] == 2016]:
   df = pd.to_csv('average2016.csv', index=False)

else:
   df = pd.to_csv('average2017.csv', index=False)
```

I have also tried using pd.Series, but it seems as though you can't use df.assign with this?

```
df = pd.Series(['1/1/2016'])

if df.item():
```

I have also attempted for loops, using the range of dates but they just skip the condition and write all of the dates to one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2016]
df1.to_csv('average2016.csv', index=False)

df2 = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2017]
df2.to_csv('average2017.csv', index=False)
```

For general solution use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('Year').apply(lambda x: x.to_csv('average{}.csv'.format(x.name), index=False))
```

Comment: This worked, however, it wrote every single column from the original file. My DF was designed to only take specific columns from the original file. I integrated your code into mine: `(df
 .loc[df['Year'] == 2016]
 .assign(MONTH=df['DATE'].dt.strftime('(%m) %B (%y)'))
 .groupby(['NAME', 'MONTH'], as_index=False)['SNOW']
 .agg({'AVERAGE': 'mean'}).to_csv('average2016.csv', index=False)
)`

Comment: @JamesPi - Yes, it working. Also I try find some solution - `df.loc[df['DATE'].dt.year == 2016, 'SNOW'].groupby([df['NAME'], df['DATE'].dt.strftime('(%m) %B (%y)')]).agg([('AVERAGE', 'mean')]).to_csv('average2016.csv')`

Comment: The original edit I made to your code in my first comment worked for me. Are you suggesting that using this has a benefit over my original? Or is that just another way of doing it

Comment: I think it is another way, not sure if worse readable or not ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can do it by directly passing the date column with `dt.year`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.date_range(start="2017-12-28",end="2018-01-04")))

for ind, dfx in df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year):
    dfx.to_csv('average{}.csv'.format(ind), index=False)
```

---

dataframe:

```
        date
0 2017-12-28
1 2017-12-29
2 2017-12-30
3 2017-12-31
4 2018-01-01
5 2018-01-02
6 2018-01-03
7 2018-01-04
```

Becomes two file, `average2017.csv` and `average2018.csv`:

```
date       date
2017-12-28 2018-01-01
2017-12-29 2018-01-02
2017-12-30 2018-01-03
2017-12-31 2018-01-04
```